# All combinations fourteen item array

Tags: python, arrays, list, combinations

So I have an array containing fourteen items. Each item can either be a 0 or a 1. I am looking for some help figuring out every combination of these digits. I have tried itertools but I cannot seem to get it to work as I would like. An example of what I mean is this.

```
   for i in range(0, 15):
       if i%2 == 0:
            array1.append(b)
       else:
            array1.append(c)

   for i in range(0, 14):
for L in range(14, 15):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(array1, L):
        if s != str(subset):
            s = str(subset)
            y += 1
                print(subset)
```

Here is the code but the obvious trouble is the array is filled in exact order l then r but what I need is each to be interchangeable.

Adding up to fourteen. Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: That's not an example - that's an input ;-)  Please give a *small* example input and the exact output you want.

Comment: post the code you tried. give an input / output example please

Comment: Exactly how does your example add up to 14?

Comment: Edited. Not add up to 14 just needs 14 elements in it. I am trying to allow each item in the array to be L or R and get all possible combos of each

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=14)
```

You can get a list of these results by doing:

```
list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=14))
```

or you can iterate over all possibilities by doing:

```
for item in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=14):
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to just count from `0` to `(1 << 14) - 1` and then consider all the binary digits of the counter; in Python:

```
for i in xrange(1 << 14):
    bits = [(i >> k) & 1 for k in xrange(14)]
    ... use bits array ...
```